# Difference of Jordan Mesurable Sets is Measurable

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that the set difference of Jordan Measurable Sets is Measurable; I am wondering if I can prove it by using the definition of measurable sets (i.e. upper and lower coincide)? I know how to prove it using $A_1 ⊂ E ⊂ B1$ and $A_2 ⊂ E ⊂ B_2$ with $m(B_i\backslash A_i) <\epsilon / 2$
for $i = 1, 2.$

Comment: To prove this by showing the equality of the inner and outer Jordan measures involves many basic properties of elementary sets and Jordan measure, with which you may or may not be familiar.  Many are intuitively obvious, e.g., the Jordan measure of an elementary set is the volume, Jordan outer measure is subbadditive, property (2) below, etc.  If you need a proof of (2) I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the definition that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan measurable if the inner and outer Jordan measures are equal, that is

$$m_*(A) :=\sup_{E \subset A} |E| = \inf_{E \supset A} |E| =: m^*(A) ,$$

where $E$ denotes an elementary set (finite union of non-overlapping rectangles) and $|E|$ is the volume of $E$. When $A$ is Jordan measurable, we denote the Jordan measure  by $m(A) = m^*(A) = m_*(A)$.

Suppose that $A \subset B$ where $A,B$ are bounded and Jordan measurable. To prove that $B \setminus A$ is Jordan measureable we must show that $m_*( B \setminus A) = m^*(B \setminus A)$.

Take any rectangle $Q$ where $A \subset B \subset Q$ and note that

$$Q \setminus(B\setminus A) = Q \cap(B \cap A^c)^c = (Q \cap B^c)\cup (Q \cap A) = (Q\setminus B) \cup A $$

We then have

$$\tag{1}m^*(Q \setminus(B\setminus A)) = m^*((Q\setminus B) \cup A ) \leqslant m^*(Q\setminus B) + m^*(A),$$

where the last inequality is obtained form the property of subbaditivity of Jordan outer measure -- $m^*(A_1 \cup A_2) \leqslant m^*(A_1) + m^*(A_2)$ -- which I leave as an exercise to prove.

Now we need another basic property that for any subset $C$ of a rectangle $Q$ we have

$$\tag{2} m^*(Q \setminus C) = |Q| - m_*(C)$$

Deferring the proof of (2) and applying it to (1) first with $C = B\setminus A$ on the LHS and then with $C = B$ on the RHS we get,

$$|Q| - m_*(B \setminus A) \leqslant |Q| - m_*(B) + m^*(A),$$

which implies

$$\tag{3} m_*(B \setminus A) \geqslant m_*(B) - m^*(A)$$

By a similar argument we can prove that

$$\tag{4} m^*(B \setminus A) \leqslant m^*(B) - m_*(A)$$

With (3) and (4) we have proved the intuitively obvious facts that the outer (inner) measure of a set difference is no bigger (smaller) than the outer (inner) measure of the superset minus the inner (outer) measure of the subset.

Substracting (4) from (3) we get

$$ 0 \leqslant m^*(B \setminus A) -  m_*(B \setminus A) \leqslant m^*(B) - m_*(B ) +   m^*(A) - m_*(A) = 0,$$

since $A$ and $B$ are by hypothesis Jordan measurable with equal inner and outer measures.

Therefore, $m^*(B \setminus A) = m_*(B \setminus A)$ and $B \setminus A$ is Jordan measureable.

Comment: Would the following approach using the difference of set characterisation of Jordan measurability also work?

Comment: Since $E$ and $F$ are jordan measurable there exist $A_{1}\subset E\subset B_{1}$ and 
$A_{2} \subset F\subset B_{2}$ s.t. $m( B_{1}\setminus A_{1}),\;  m( B_{2} \setminus A_{2})<\epsilon $. W.l.o.g. 
assume $F\subset E$ meaning
$A_{1}\setminus B_{2}\subset E\setminus F\subset B_{1} \setminus A_{2}$ yielding
        \begin{aligned}
        m( ( B_{1} \setminus A_{2})\setminus ( A_{1}\setminus B_{2})) 
        = m( B_{1}) - m\left( A_{2}\right) + m( B_{2}) -m( A_{2}) 
        < 2\epsilon 
        .\end{aligned}
      (the case where $A_{1}\subset B_{2}$ is analogous).